# detener main.py en raspberry pi pico. con thomy

Tags: micropython

puse a correr un programa encoder con tiempo en 2 modulos distintos, lo guarde en pi pico y no puedo detenerlo para editar, ni puedo abrir el arhivo en la raspberry. intente de todo como: repetir stop, cambiar de puerto, reiniciar mi computadora, reiniciar el programa thomy, y cada vez que lo conecto sigue dando los tiempos pero no puedo ver los archivos en la pico. intente reinstalar el sofware y no pasa nada, como puedo detenerlo?
GRacias.

Comment: Aprieta el botón de Boot y reinstala micropython. En mi experiencia, no se pierden los scripts. Cuando lo reinstalas, entrarás en modo REPL o Terminal, aprovecha esa instancia para modificar los scripts antes de reiniciarlo